# How to generate the same class name for UL element under LI using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, foreach

I have tried to generate/create the class name dynamically in the `ul` element and I have got the expected result successfully which can be seen in the console of the snippet for reference.

But I'm trying to create the same class name if the `ul` is generated under a `li` element. For example, there is a `li` element with the class name `"a"` and if we create multiple `ul` elements under the same `li` element the class name of `ul` should be the same as below but instead of that the class gets counted.

The result I need:

```
<li class="a">
    <a href="/">First</a>
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b">
            <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
            <ul class="main-nav-list ul-1"> //The ul-1 should be static (even after dyanmic class generated) to the next ul li example if ul-1 one come the next li with ul should also have the same class ul-1
                <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li class="b">
            <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
            <ul class="main-nav-list ul-1">
                <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

The code I have tried so far

```js
var ul = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav ul");

ul.forEach((each, i) => {
    each.classList.add("ul-" + i);
    console.log(each)
});
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  
  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li class="a">
      <a href="/">First</a>
      
      <ul class="main-nav-list"> 
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

[image]

If First Ul has class ul-0 then the next ul should also have ul-0 as a class.
Any Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: Is there anyway you can try to work on the description a little bit more? This is kind of confusing. Feel free to go in depth as you would like.

Comment: Your 2 HTML snippets are not the same which also makes it a bit confusing. I think you're going to need two loops, one to get an outer collection and another to loop the inner `ul`s.

Comment: I have updated comments on code, If I create two loops then the class name will be generated as a dynamic one but in my case, I'm trying to achieve the class name as a static one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select each `li` and for each of them iterate over its `ul`s, then add any class you want to them.

```js
// selecting li's of main ul in the page
var lis = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav>ul>li");

lis.forEach((each) => {

    // selecting all uls inside each li
    let innerUls = each.querySelectorAll(`:scope>ul`)


    // adding class name to each ul
    innerUls.forEach((itm, index) => {
      itm.classList.add("ul-" + index);
    })
});
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  
  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li class="a">
      <a href="/">First</a>
      
      <ul class="main-nav-list"> 
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
    
    <li class="a">
      <a href="/">Second</a>
      
      <ul class="main-nav-list"> 
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="main-nav-list"> 
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul class="main-nav-list"> 
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Adding class to `ul`s recursively

```js
let classNames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
function addClassToUls(ul, level) {
  var lis = ul.querySelectorAll(':scope>li');
  lis.forEach((each) => {

    // selecting all uls inside each li
    let innerUls = each.querySelectorAll(`:scope>ul`)


    // adding class name to each ul
    innerUls.forEach((itm, index) => {
      itm.classList.add(`ul-${level}-${classNames[index]}`);
      addClassToUls(itm, level+1);
    })
  })
}

let mainUls = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav>ul");

mainUls.forEach(ul => addClassToUls(ul, 1))
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">

  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li class="a">
      <a href="/">First</a>

      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="a">
      <a href="/">Second</a>

      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">// In my case, if the class is ul-1 then next li ul is generating as ul-2 but i want it to be same in the both the li component
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="b">
          <a href="/">Type of menu</a>

          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"><a href="/">Summer</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: In My scenario, I want this to be achieved in every li>ul with classes and again in one ul has ul-one as a class the next separate ul also has ul-one as class I have attached a screenshot for reference.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it @ScriptHost